# Dynamo in Revit 2020/2021 wont import sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, ironpython, revit-api

Using the following imports in a python node in Dynamo for Revit 2020 or 2021 (2019 and 2022 work fine)

```
import clr
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
clr.AddReference('C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\DLLs\IronPython.SQLite')
import sqlite3
```

I get the following error

```
Warning: IronPythonEvaluator.EvaluateIronPythonScript operation failed. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2021\AddIns\DynamoForRevit\IronPython.StdLib.2.7.9\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2021\AddIns\DynamoForRevit\IronPython.StdLib.2.7.9\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

Adding the full path to the dll reference fixed is problem in Revit 2019, but no such luck with 2020 and 2021

> clr.AddReference('C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\DLLs\IronPython.SQLite')

Why would Dynamo not being seeing these imports?

Comment: I cannot answer your question myself, but I can suggest that you may access a larger and very competent audience addressing this directly to the [Dynamo discussion forum](https://forum.dynamobim.com).

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an answer as to why, but found that these paths and references got the import to work. Incase it helps anyone else.

Revit 2019

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
clr.AddReference(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\DLLs\IronPython.SQLite.dll")
```

Revit 2020

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\AddIns\DynamoForRevit')
clr.AddReferenceToFile('IronPython.SQLite.dll')
```

Revit 2021

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
clr.AddReference(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\DLLs\IronPython.SQLite.dll")
```

Revit 2022

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
clr.AddReferenceToFile('IronPython.SQLite.dll')
```